# Use environment variable in Jenkins pipeline options{} block

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to use an env var in Jenkins' pipeline `options {}` block, but it seems they aren't extrapolated at that stage. Am I missing something or is it intentional and there's no way to make it work?

Example:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image '...'
            label 'docker'
        }
    }
    environment {
        MAGIC_APP_NAME = "xxx"
        MAGIG_APP_ID = "yyy"
    }
    options {
        connection: gitLabConnection("GitLab-${env.MAGIC_APP_ID}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve that issue? I am facing the same scenario and looking for a solution.

Comment: @julew To be completely honest - I have no ideas, been quite a long time ago, previous life :) Don't have access to that code anymore unfortunately.